# Amasty Improved layered Navigation loads luma theme instead of custome theme on brand pages

Tags: theme, amasty

I have Magento 2.4.5 and am using Amasty Improved Layered Navigation, specifically this question refers to shop by brand.
In magento I have multistores setup with a different theme for each storeview.
When I click on a brand page (created by amasty extension) on my website the theme reverts back to Magento Luma theme.

My question is. How can I tell the extension to use the theme aplied to the storeview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved. For anyones information. The Amasty brand features bases its theme on the theme of the Root category in Magento. So you have to update the theme of your Root category to match the theme that is selected for that storeview. Then it works.